# Move to v2 API with express self hosting

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like used the V2 API on my dialogflow fullfilment.
But when I self hosting an express, only v1 works, Why ?

With firebase functions both V1 and V2 works with the same code.

I apply this : https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration,

Error for the welcome intent :

Request from simulator

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHHtohp6Z0QsGp9X_TSwUK3gCxdRwCZ5w3kXR-iI-aXiUSNZR3Vuo59vocUIgP80gE2qWs2SFKk-fI6g83YJjA",
    "locale": "fr-CA",
    "lastSeen": "2019-02-25T15:29:15Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "ABwppHHfpVWINKIQFvk-bzrVSvu4s-8JexXgZXP7FQ-NQ5HmPAneHtGY0u86_llCV--tj3TZpMtCMIMCZakyxc7mYQ",
    "type": "NEW"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "Parler avec le diable"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

reponse from simulator :

```
{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"50104e9c-79ec-4545-a510-88ffd1944af7\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-02-25T15:32:35.568Z\",\"lang\":\"fr-ca\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 400 Bad Request\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHHfpVWINKIQFvk-bzrVSvu4s-8JexXgZXP7FQ-NQ5HmPAneHtGY0u86_llCV--tj3TZpMtCMIMCZakyxc7mYQ\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Simulator :

[image: img]

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you include how you're generating a response?

Comment: I edited the post with a screen capture of simulator

Comment: How do you create the response? Can you include a code snippet?

Comment: I create the response in app,intent 'play audiobook' : [code](https://github.com/panaC/VoiceAssistant/blob/actions/actions-server/express/src/app/app.ts). And [express code](https://github.com/panaC/VoiceAssistant/blob/actions/actions-server/express/src/server.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was a wrong express configuration with bodyparser.

This is my code :

```
import express from 'express';
import { SERVER_NAME, ENTRY_POINT, PORT } from './constants';
import { app } from './app/app';

export const server = express();

server.set('port', PORT);
server.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
server.use(express.json({}));
server.post(ENTRY_POINT, app);
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(SERVER_NAME);
});
```

just used express.use() instead body parser with express 4.16. It seems to me that it resolve the problem. Now V2 API with dialogflow seems works.